# HTML, CSS place div at the left instead of right of relative element

Tags: html, css

I have this code snippet:

```css
#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  background: silver;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="wrap">
    <img class="fit-img" src="~/Content/img/Assets/image.jpg">
    <div id="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to place the DIV with the ID `text` at the left, not the right side of wrapped content. Any tips?

Comment: What's the overall objective here for the layout? I ask because there's many ways to accomplish this. Some ways are better than other depending on your requirements.

Comment: div with id "text", makes a black transparent box on the right side of the image. I wish i could put it on the left side instead...

Comment: So you want to overlay the text on top of the image?

Comment: Johannes already gave me a solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just erase `right: 0;` and replace it with `left: 0;` in here:

```
#text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```